# SonarQube reports no dependencies, 0 Tangle index, for C# solution with 12K+ classes?

Tags: c#, sonarqube

We recently setup SonarQube analysis jobs for our main .Net applications, 6 of them totally 4.4 million lines of code and some 35K+ classes between them.  We are getting lots of interesting information but the design analysis does not seem to be working at all.  The tangle index is zero for all of projects and when we open up the design tool for any of them we get a list of all the folders/namespaces in the project but none of them have any dependancies on any of the other folders/namespaces.

Any ideas on how to debug this?  I looked through the logs but obviously with projects this size, unless I really know what I am looking for, grepping logs is needle-in-haystack work.

This is using SQ 5.1 with the 4.0 version of the C# plugin and v 1.2 of the analysis bootstrapper for VS projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even if I do understand that this might be misleading, not having any information about dependencies/librairies/design on C# projects is expected. FYI, in SQ 5.2, all those pages and relating metrics will be dropped, see the following Jira ticket: http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6553.